# Can I access the props or state of a Pagination component being generated by an Ant Design Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, pagination, antd

I have an Ant Design Table in my code and I am passing it a pagination prop as follows:

```
<Table
  dataSource={alerts}
  pagination={{
    pageSize: 9,
    position: 'bottomLeft',
    showSizeChanger: false
  }}
  columns={columns}
/>
```

In my React component tree, I can see a `Pagination` component, that has both a `props` and `state` value of `current` (tells you/sets the current page you are on) that I want access to, so I can save it & pass it around.

[image]

However, I don't know how to get access to this value because I don't actually have a `Pagination` component in my React code, the `Pagination` component is just being generated by the `pagination` prop in the `Table` component. Is it possible to access this value somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the Pagination props and state from the component above the Table/Pagination. That's against how React works, because the data here flows only in one direction. From top components to bottom components.

However, there is a way, the pagination properties that you need, can be returned via Pagination event handlers. So, you could save them in state in the component that uses Antd Table.

At the code below I am using API provided by the Table component. The `onChange` and `onShowSizeChange` return the actual Pagination state values, that then I save to the state. I was referring to the documentation of Pagination component [here](https://ant.design/components/pagination/).

```js
const dataSource = [{
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
];

const columns = [{
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      currentPageSize: 1,
      currentPage: 1,
    }
    onPageChange = (page: number, pageSize ? : number) => {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: page,
        currentPageSize: pageSize
      });
    }

    onPageSizeChange = (page: number, pageSize: number) => {
      this.setState({
        currentPage: page,
        currentPageSize: pageSize
      });
    }
    render() {
      return ( < Table dataSource = {
          dataSource
        }
        pagination = {
          {
            pageSize: this.state.currentPageSize,
            current: this.state.currentPage,
            onChange: this.onPageChange,
            onShowSizeChange: this.onPageSizeChange
          }
        }
        columns = {
          columns
        }
        />);
      }
    }

    render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Terminant , nicely done ! bravo